# Error msg: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Boolean

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I am getting an error msg when attempting to update a record from asp.net into a SQL database. The only boolean value being updated is:

```
cmdAddUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Active", SqlDbType.Bit));
cmdAddUser.Parameters["@Active"].Value = 
    Convert.ToBoolean(cbAddUserActiveUser.Checked);
```

The datatype for @Active in the database is "bit". Any ideas?

Comment: @user279521: You aren't really indicating what error you are getting.  Try posting the exception information that you are getting so we can determine if it is a parse issue (on the call to ToBoolean) or something on the database side.

Comment: "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Boolean." is the error message.

Comment: Wild guess, but try `Convert.ToBoolean(cbAddUserActiveUser.Checked.ToString());`

Comment: @Jason.... No luck.... Same error

Comment: What about trying without the convert.toboolean?  Isn't .checked already a boolean value?

Comment: I think casperOne is asking for the stack trace so we can see what is causing the error - the Convert.ToBoolean or the .Value = x.

Comment: From the help "Bit - Boolean. An unsigned numeric value that can be 0, 1, or null (Nothing in Visual Basic)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long shot - have you got another parameter that is set as a string but is a bit column in the actual table?

Comment: Good answer. I am modifying this proc that has about 24 paramters.